# Solving linear equations with one unknown with Python

Tags: python, linear-algebra, sympy, equation

If assuming equations is equaled to 0, it is fairly simple to do by using:

```
from sympy import *

x = Symbol("x")
print(solve([x + 5], x))
```

x would be -5, because the equation is equaled to 0. 
However, what if we want the equation is equaled to something else, like 10? I've read the [Sympy document](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html), and can't seem to find a solution for it.

This is a similar question I have here, how do I calculate this equation using Python?

x = 5(x-4)

Comment: replace `x + 5` with `x + 5 - 10`?

Comment: I guess what I try to do is to not modify the equation itself, not sure if there is other way to go around it though.

Comment: Could you be more specific? In most situations you can replace `RightHandSide = LeftHandSide` with `RightHandSide - LeftHandSide = 0` without any loss of generality. Is there any reason why modifying the equation is problematic?

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko, I feel so dumb here... I was originally thinking how do I put the equation in the code, because it can only be `x + 5`, not `x + 5 = x`, that's why I don't want to modify it, but you actually gave me a clue on this, thank you... ah math...

Comment: I with I had a penny for every time this happened to me :)

Answer (score 0):

[Sympy documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html#algebraic-equations) states:

> The first argument for solve() is an equation (equaled to zero) and the second argument is the symbol that we want to solve the equation for.

so you have to pass a equation which is equal to zero.